# Rearrange RadioOption in jetpack-compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I want to randomly rearrange the three lables of `RadioOption`, with the first taking the place of the second and the third replacing the first when they are displayed.

```
@Composable
fun MyUI() {
    val radioOptions = listOf("Linux", "Mac", "Windows")

    var selectedItem by remember {
        mutableStateOf(radioOptions[0])
    }

    Column(modifier = Modifier.selectableGroup()) {
        radioOptions.forEach { label ->
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(56.dp)
                    .selectable(
                        selected = (selectedItem == label),
                        onClick = { selectedItem = label },
                        role = Role.RadioButton
                    )
                    .padding(horizontal = 16.dp),
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
            ) {
                Icon(
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(end = 16.dp),
                    imageVector = if (selectedItem == label)
                        Icons.Outlined.CheckCircle else
                        Icons.Outlined.RadioButtonUnchecked,
                    // screen readers will read the Text() compsable content
                    // if we pass label here, they end up reading the content twice
                    // so, pass null
                    contentDescription = null,
                    tint = Color.Magenta
                )
                Text(text = label)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is how it should look likes :
[image]

Answer (score 2):

**shuffled():-** list with the elements of this list randomly shuffled.

```
val radioOptions = listOf("Linux", "Mac", "Windows").shuffled()
```